# Deleting All the similar object from array if it has duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects with duplicates:

```js
[
  {
    "code": "d1",
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "code": "d2",
    "title": "Title 2"
  },
  {
    "code": "d3",
    "title": "Title 3"
  },
  {
    "code": "d4",
    "title": "Title 4"
  },
  {
    "code": "d4",
    "title": "Title 4"
  },
  {
    "code": "d3",
    "title": "Title 3"
  }
]
```

So i want the output to be having only the once which doesn't have duplicates included like below:

```js
[
  {
    "code": "d1",
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "code": "d2",
    "title": "Title 2"
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: can do using a filter inside a filter. in the inner filter check if the length === 1

Comment: `const r = data.filter(
  (v) => data.filter((x) => x.code === v.code).length === 1
);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
const products=[
  {
"code": "d1",
"title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
"code": "d2",
"title": "Title 2"
  },
  {
"code": "d3",
"title": "Title 3"
  },
  {
"code": "d4",
"title": "Title 4"
  },
  {
"code": "d4",
"title": "Title 4"
  },
  {
"code": "d3",
"title": "Title 3"
  }
];

const res=Object.entries(products.reduce((a,c)=>{
   (a[c.code+"|"+c.title]??=[]).push(c);
   return a;
 },{})).reduce((a,[k,v])=>{
   if(v.length==1) a.push(v[0]);
   return a;
 },[]);

console.log(res);
```

My approach involves two `.reduce()` loops:

- In the first one I generate an object that collects all elements of the original array behind a compound key made up of the properties of the elements.
- the object is then converted into an array again with `Object.entries()`
- and in a second `.reduce()` only those elements will be collected (i. e.: their first element) into the target array that have a length of `1`

Answer (score 1):

- Find unique's values in an array.

```js
const ressult = YourArray.filter(
  (value, index, array) => array.findIndex((v) => v.code === value.code) === index
);
```

Comment: This will still give you all unique values, but what i want is to remove the duplicates entirely. The expected result is this:
[
  {
    "code": "d1",
    "title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "code": "d2",
    "title": "Title 2"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

```js
        let val = [
          {
            "code": "d1",
            "title": "Title 1"
          },
          {
            "code": "d2",
            "title": "Title 2"
          },
          {
            "code": "d3",
            "title": "Title 3"
          },
          {
            "code": "d4",
            "title": "Title 4"
          },
          {
            "code": "d4",
            "title": "Title 4"
          },
          {
            "code": "d3",
            "title": "Title 3"
          }
        ];
        let distinctVal = getDistincts(val);
        function getDistincts(val){
          let obj={};
          for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            obj[`${val[i]["code"]}`]=val[i]["title"];
          }
          return obj;
        }
        console.log(distinctVal);
```